# How to determine mouse's position is close enough to a path?

Tags: svg, d3.js, mouseevent

I'm developing a chart with d3.js. There's this functionality I don't have a clue how to implement:  I have a polyline on the chart, and I want to highlight it(make it bolder, turn into other color) when the mouse is close enough to any point of this polyline.

I don't know if there's some built in function in d3 to determine if mouse is close to me(the svg element). If not, then how to implement this?

Assume the above functionality is ready, how do I make the highlighted polyline can be dragged when the mouse is close to this line but not actually on this line?

Answer (score 0):

Try making each point have a very large border like 5px, but make the border transparent and use the background-clip property to ensure the background does not extend into the border.

Then you can use mouseover actions and trigger effects [change color, make larger] on the cicles.

This way the circles look the same size but have a hidden border of 5px that respond to mouseover events.  So hovering close to a circle but not touching will trigger events since it really is touching the transparent border.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Voronoi tessellation, as shown in Mike Bostock's example [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/8033015). The idea is to create polygons over the entire chart so that you can determine the closest point to where the mouse is anywhere on the chart. There are some other great example to demonstrate this [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060366) and [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4360892).

This adds a really nice effect, and allows you to highlight the closest point on the line, as well as just the closest line itself. This is really not too difficult to implement from the examples, but if you want a simpler solution you can use the transparent circle border method described by link13. Or add another polyline with a thick stroke-width and set its opacity to 0, and add the hover listener to that.

Comment: Here's an example of the invisible stroke based solution: http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/interactivity/hover-invisible-stroke-compat.svg (shapes change fill when mouse is closer than 20px to the shape)